# Flutter notiftyListeners contuniously rebuilding

Tags: flutter, provider, state-management, consumer

This is my service function that communicate with the database

```
Future<News?> getNewsList(String token) async {
var url = Uri.tryParse('${baseUrl}get-news-list');
var response =
    await http.post(url!, headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'});
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var map = json.decode(response.body);
  var list = News.fromJson(map);
  print("map:${list.data![0]}");
  return News.fromJson(map);
} else {
  return News(message: null, status: false, data: null);
}
```

}

This my viewModel class I am using mvvm pattern

```
class NewsViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
ApiOp api = ApiOp();

Future<List<NewsModel?>?> getNews() async {
String token ="token-here";
var map = await api.getNewsList(token);

List<NewsModel?>? list = map!.data;
print("object:${list![0]!.title}");
notifyListeners();
return list;
```

}
}

And here where I show the data on the view

```
 Consumer<NewsViewModel?>(
                builder: (context, value, child) => FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
                    future: value!.getNews(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      List? list = snapshot.data;
                      
                      print("list:$list");
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 2,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return FirsatWidget(
                            title:"",
                            date: "",
                            photoUrl: "lib/assets/temp/4.jpg",
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    }),
              ),
```

But when I run the app some print function spamming in the debug like these prints
print("object:${list![0]!.title}");
print("map:${list.data![0]}");
Is this code continuously send post to the server or just rebuilding the consumer

Answer (score 0):

> Is this code continuously send post to the server or just rebuilding
> the consumer

You are continuosly sending http reqests to your server.

You don't need to use `Consumer<NewsViewModel?>` and `notifyListeners();` because you are using FutureBuilder which gets data from that future.

Try this code:

```
FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
                    future: Provider.of<NewsViewModel>(context,listen:false).getNews(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      List? list = snapshot.data;
                      
                      print("list:$list");
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 2,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return FirsatWidget(
                            title:"",
                            date: "",
                            photoUrl: "lib/assets/temp/4.jpg",
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    }),
              ),
```

And comment notifyListeners()

```
class NewsViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
ApiOp api = ApiOp();

Future<List<NewsModel?>?> getNews() async {
String token ="token-here";
var map = await api.getNewsList(token);

List<NewsModel?>? list = map!.data;
print("object:${list![0]!.title}");
// notifyListeners();
return list;
```

Let me know if you have issues and still have rebuilds.

Comment: yes this is preventing the spams but when i add some data to the database it wont refresh the view page automatically.How can i solve that

Comment: FutureBuilder receives data once. But you can use RefreshIndicator to update your data, however it is not automatically updated if there is any change in db. Or you can use StreamBuilder(I myself only used it with Cloud Firestore) instead of FutureBuilder

Comment: Also, do you add data by sending request from this app ? If yes, it is much easier to implement

Comment: I found that the code( your original ) you used can be improved by changing places of Consumer and FutureBuilder. It's not good that FutureBuilder's parent is Consumer since with every notification Consumer is rebuilt thus it(Consumer) rebuilds FutureBuilder again and again. there is infinite loop as far as I understood

Comment: yes i guess you're right .there is an infinite loop.But when i changed places of Consumer and FB then when i insert data to database it is still not rebuilding the view.Btw i have a admin panel to insert new data.I think i should use StreamBuilder or FutureProvider idk.I will try.